# How to solve this Python error when inserting list in database?

Tags: python, sql

I'm trying to insert into database a list (that I extracted from a file) with 3 columns:

- log_time
- log_type
- message

I used this code:

```
#database connection
try:
    #Connection object for connection to azure sql database
    print( "Connecting to database..." )
    params = urllib.parse.quote_plus(
    'Driver=%s;' % driver +
    'Server=tcp:%s,1433;' % server +
    'Database=%s;' % database +
    'Uid=%s;' % username +
    'Pwd={%s};' % password +
    'Encrypt=yes;' +
    'TrustServerCertificate=no;' +
    'Connection Timeout=30;')
    
    conn_str = 'mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=' + params

    global engine        
    engine = create_engine(conn_str,echo=False, fast_executemany=True)

except:
    print('Cannot connect to destination database. Database is not available or connection information is incorrect. Please, review.')



with open("test.log",'r') as data_file:
    for line in data_file:
        values = [line.rstrip('\n').split("\\") for line in data_file]
        final_list = [ list(filter(lambda l: l != '', inside_l)) for inside_l in values]
        print(final_list)


query = 'INSERT INTO control (log_time, log_type, message) VALUES (%s, %s, %s);'
engine.execute(query, final_list)
```

Yet, when I execute the script it gives me this error:

```
... displaying 10 of 15 total bound parameter sets ...
```

By the way, when  I print the list, is something like this:

```
['2022-04-28 22:33:07,470', 'DEBUG', 'Files concatenation'], ...
```

Comment: And what do you see when you print `query`?

Comment: If I print query it shows:

INSERT INTO control (log_time, log_type, message) VALUES (%s, %s, %s);